# How do I set the version of IE used by an Outlook VSTO Add-in?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, vsto

I'm having difficulty finding information on this. I have a Winforms Webbrowser control in my VSTO Outlook add-in.

In other .net projects using this control, I changed it's IE version by setting a registry key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION specifying my exe with one of the [ie values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx), but if I make one for OUTLOOK.exe nothing happens.

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine, you might need to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION instead.

Comment: Changed that one too and it didn't affect anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/office-365-proplus-outlook-ie-browser-emulation/b1264b5d-93b0-4f49-8c40-752a1f0f563b

Basically you need to change the below registry

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

This key will be the precedence.
So setting this key will force your Webbrowser control to use desired IE version